# in R mutate TRUE FALSE to 1 0

Tags: r, boolean

I'm new so this may be a dumb question. Don't overthink it.
I have a tibble with a column useMFH that is a logical value
( I confirm header says "lgl" ) and has values that display as TRUE or FALSE

I simply want a new variable zz that is 1 if useMFH is TRUE,
and 0 otherwise.

I tried the following but it just results in zz being a column of 0's.  I'm misundestanding something really basic.

df2 <- df %>% mutate(zz = case_when(isTRUE(useMFH) ~ 1,TRUE ~ 0))

What should I have used? What am I misunderstanding concepually? thank you.

Comment: `as.numeric(useMFH)`.

Comment: Add 0 to that column.

Comment: `isTRUE()` is to identify a **single** event is `T` or `F`. E.g. `x <- 1; isTRUE(x == 1)` returns `T`. Your `useMFH` is a logical vector that contains multiple logical elements, so `isTRUE()` cannot apply on it. It'll return a single `FALSE`. An example is `isTRUE(c(T,T,T))`. Even all elements in the vector are `T`, `isTRUE()` still returns `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends slightly on if your data type is truly a boolean, which can be checked via `str()`. If is a string or logical data type changes the approach a bit. You can use case when but can skip the `isTRUE()` and `mutate()` function (though they could work but are not needed). Example below:

```
# dataframe with column st as string and bol as logical 
x <- data.frame(st = c('TRUE', 'FALSE'), bol = c(TRUE,FALSE))

# see the data type
str(x)

# if string
x$new <- case_when(x$st == 'FALSE' ~ 0,
                         TRUE ~ 1)
# if logical
x$new_log <- case_when(x$bol == F ~ 0,
                       TRUE ~ 1)
```

Additionally, `ifelse` would work here, too.

Comment: So your last line worked for me which solve how to do this.  But I still don't understand why my original attempt failed.  is the syntax incorrect?

Comment: If a column is truly a boolean, `==T` or `==F` is redundant. Just `case_when( !x$bol ~ 0, TRUE ~ 1)`.